# How to create a datetime object in javascript when using javascript remoteTK/remote toolkit

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am new to salesforce and I know my question sounds silly. But I need someone to tell me the direction I should go.

My question is how can I convert string or object like this

```
{Start_time__C:"2014-07-24T20:55:00.000+0000"}
```

and this

```
{perDiem: true}
```

into salesforce object. And then I can use create function in remoteTK.

I am currently building custom app on salesforce1. In my visualforce page, I need to create new record, which has datetime, and boolean as its fields.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the [remoteTK](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) but before you deep dive into it you might want to look into the "Remote Objects" from Spring'14. This seems to be the new hip / official way of doing remoting (which doesn't mean I'm saying rTK is bad!) and slightly easier to use.

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33072/visualforce-remote-objects
- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/03/spring-14-using-visualforce-remote-objects-with-canjs.html
- http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/22/spring14-visualforce-remote-objects-introduction/
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_example_extended.htm

The main difference between them seems to be that you could use rTK in a non-visualforce page as underneath it just relies on REST callouts. The remote objects use a special VF tag so it's VF-only.

---

In the end I think it won't matter much which library you'll use. Sample remote object code:

```
// Create work order line item
var workOrderLineItem = new SObjectModel.WorkOrderLineItem__c();
workOrderLineItem.set('Description__c', 'Answering the question');
workOrderLineItem.set('Hours__c', answer);
workOrderLineItem.set('WorkOrder__c', result[0]);
workOrderLineItem.create(function(error, result, event)
    {
        // Errors?
        if(error!=null)
            alert(error);
        else
            alert('Success');
    });
```

vs. the sample from remoteTK:

```
var objectType = 'Account';
var fields = {'Name': 'salesforce.com', 'Description':'CRM'};

client.create(objectType , fields,
    function(response) {
        getAccounts(function() {
            $j.mobile.pageLoading(true);
            $j.mobile.changePage('#mainpage', "slide", true, true);
        });
    }, errorCallback);
```

So a JavaScript object with fields is being created in both cases. For **Booleans** you should be good sending `'true'` or `'false'` strings.

For **dates** you might have to experiment a bit. Generally I've been passing Unix timestamp (miliseconds since Jan 1 1970), this seemed to work OK for me in REST calls or Visualforce Remoting (by which I mean `@RemoteAction` stuff, yet another tool).

The [`RemoteTKController.writeFields()`](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/RemoteTKController.cls#L40) seems to be using `Date.valueOf(someString)` when casting. This means the format should be ['yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) which is close enough - check if it will work out of the box and remove the timezone part from your string if it causes problems? You could simplify your examples a lot by skipping the remote part and directly check in Developer Console or Execute Anonymous how the parser reacts to different dates you'll feed it.

There's [another function](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/bed85b46b5e0b6ce3f381786151cd1d7329b5bbe/forcetk.js#L344) that seems to use REST API instead of the controller. This one will just pass the payload to REST API's POST request. Looking at how it's built you should be fine just passing a real JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object as value, the `JSON.stringify` call should figure out how to serialize that. If you really want to craft the string yourself - check the REST API guide. [The dates should look like that](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_get_deleted.htm) and all remoteTK'create call does is make a [request similar to this one](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm)

Comment: Thank you eyescream. I played around it but still no luck. So I am going to use RemoteAction, I guess that's my best bet, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but in case it helps someone I was able to get this working. The yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format was very close. All it needed was a 'T' between the date and time to be acceptable. From there is was just making sure that all components came through as two digits, and converting the date to UTC time. Here's my final Javascript function:

```
function ConvertDate(dtin){
   var d = new Date(dtin);
   var convertdate = d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +'T' + ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)+':'+d.getUTCSeconds()+'0';
   return convertdate;
}
```

From there I could pass the converted date to the sObject function without error.